# Rails: "Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value:" when trying to save "params.inspect"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character-encoding

I am trying to save to database the output of params (I am saving this: `params.inspect`) - here's an example of the string that's supposed to be saved:

```
> {\"utf8\"=>\"✓\", \"_method\"=>\"patch\", \"authenticity_token\"=>\"fpQC8FY8+qztD41jjcFSJRars539KRshw/vczmmJd9Q=\",
> \"car\"=>{\"role_type\"=>\"1\", \"admin_id\"=>\"67\",
> \"branch_id\"=>\"1\", \"template_id\"=>\"21\", \"cost\"=>\"0.00\",
> \"carrier_additional_cost\"=>\"0.00\", ...
```

First, I tried to save the params like this:

```
all_params      = params.except(:controller, :action).inspect
```

but it didn't work out. So:

```
all_params      = params.except(:controller, :action).inspect.encode("iso-8859-1")
```

Also this:

```
all_params      = params.except(:controller, :action).inspect.encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
```

returns the same error.

How to properly save the output from `params.inspect`?

The column where I try to save this data is `text`, not `string`.

Thank you

Comment: What's the unexpected string value? Is it `✓`?

Comment: I believe so - everything else looks like a "normal" character...

Comment: What does `params.to_s.encoding` give you?

Comment: Have you tried to force the encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: @13aal - yes, it's shown in the OP in the latest block code.

Comment: `✓` cannot be encoded in "iso-8859-1".  It is hex `E29C93` in utf8.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `params` instead of `params.inspect`.

A sample output of `params` is
`{"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"1"}`
which is a hash which I think is what you want to save in your database.